# How to clean pipe cleaner so that it does not rust?

Tags: cleaning, personal-care, safety, wire

I am using [pipe cleaners as an adjuster for my masks](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/a/23651/30783). How can I clean the pipe cleaner so that it does not rust?

I have read that when washed they rust. And in summary this is [bad for health](https://sciencing.com/rust-dust-harmful-8606864.html).

Any help is kindly appreciated

Comment: The pipe-cleaner solution offered by @Stan in your earlier question is a good solution, but they are really cheap. One online shopping site is selling 140 cleaners for 4 GBP, which is less than 3 pennies each. I suggest discarding it and not trying to clean. And for about the same price you can buy a reel of 2 or 3 mm aluminium wire as suggested in an answer here.

Comment: @WeatherVane OK, I'll try with the reel of 2 or 3 mm aluminum wire. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

pipe cleaners rust when they are kept in a damp state. If you want to wash them in soap and water, you have to dry them out thoroughly when done- or else they will rust.

a better solution is to use *aluminum wire* inserted into a seam in the mask for maintaining shape.  aluminum wire will not rust and is sold in hardware stores for hanging pictures on walls. If a single strand is not stiff enough, multiple strands of it can easily be twisted together to form a stiffer wire.

It is not expensive, and can be easily cut with a small hand tool called a diagonal cutter, also available in hardware stores.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'll try the aluminum wire.

Comment: Aluminium wire is brittle: bend it a few times and it'll break. Copper wire is better in this regard.

Comment: True, but copper will turn the cloth green. Commercially-made dust masks use a thin, glued-on aluminum strip over the bridge of the nose to make it conform. Seems to work fine.